# have same obtained marks in 1st,2nd and 3rd position in result table, php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

[image]

I have the above table in which i have stored result of a class. I can get the First,Second and Third position holders. 
My Problem is that i need to display 1st,2nd and 3rd position holders if there are 4 students who have the same number in first position and like 7 other students who also have the same marks and got second position and same for 3rd position holders.

Please guide me how i can write the best query to print the multiple students in 1st, 2nd and 3rd position holders with same marks.

I am using mysql database with PHP.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the code ? Where is the SQL tables structure ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just need only this table from which i have to print / get the following result:<br /> in the above table if 3 students having 450 obtained Marks 5 students having 430 obtained marks and 7 students having 400 obtained marks i need to get 3 students in one columns heading first position holder, 5 students in second column and 7 students in the third position holder column

Comment: You said that you are using MySQL and PHP. Show as some code. Also, we need to know the structure of the database in order to answer your question.